# how to get text from span in python using scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm placing here HTML code :

```
<div class="rendering rendering_person rendering_short rendering_person_short">
  <h3 class="title">
    <a rel="Person" href="https://moh-it.pure.elsevier.com/en/persons/massimo-eraldo-abate" class="link person"><span>Massimo Eraldo Abate</span></a>
  </h3>
  <ul class="relations email">
    <li class="email"><a href="massimo.abate@ior.it" class="link"><span>massimo.abate@ior.it</span></a></li>
  </ul>
  <p class="type"><span class="family">Person: </span>Academic</p>
</div>
```

From above code how to extract Massimo Eraldo Abate?

Please help me.

Answer (score 7):

You can extract the name using

```
response.xpath('//h3[@class="title"]/a/span/text()').extract_first()
```

Also, look at this Scrapinghub's [blogpost](https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2016/10/27/an-introduction-to-xpath-with-examples/) for introduction to XPath.

Comment: xpath and regex skillz are a must for getting watcha want ... xpath in-depth knowledge will save you so much hastle... look up xpath syntax like preceding-siblings andfollowing-sibbling ... anscestor child nod etc etc... helps a lot with pagination in particular I find

Answer (score 0):

Please take  a look at this page. there are lots of ways of extracting text 
[scrapy docs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html)

```
>>> body = '<html><body><span>good</span></body></html>'
>>> Selector(text=body).xpath('//span/text()').extract()

>>> response = HtmlResponse(url='http://example.com', body=body)
>>> Selector(response=response).xpath('//span/text()').extract()
```